# Kivy Crash Course (failed to make a apk)

Tags: android, python, ubuntu, kivy

I'm trying to make an app using the Kivy framework on Windows. I'm using an Ubuntu virtual machine and following [Alexander Taylor's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8N_8WkALdE). Even though I did all the required installations, when I launched the `buildozer android debug deploy` command, the terminal displayed the following message :

```
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python build.py --name 'Kivy Crash Course 2'
--version 1.0 --package org.test.kivycrash2 --private
/home/aurelien/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --orientation
sensor --window debug
```

If you want more information, please ask me.

Comment: why dont you follow the kivy tutorial that includes a virtual disk image of the OS with all requirements?

Comment: Please edit your buildozer.spec and change the line `log_level = 1` to `log_level = 2` and rebuild. This will display all of the python-for-android output and will include the actual error.

Comment: I have already changed this line...

Comment: So I tried with log_level = 1 and I got the same message...

Comment: Always the same message...

Comment: Have you got any idea ?